Does polyfills chain attack and polyfills in angular related?
I have projects in Angular 14 and 15, and vue project. There is security warning on Polyfills chain attack.
I want to know if this attack is related to angular's file polyfills.ts and does the angulars 14 to 15 and vue is safe?
https://www.theregister.com/2024/06/25/polyfillio_china_crisis/?force_isolation=true

I'd suggest to read the article again to rule out any misunderstanding. It clearly says about polyfill.io website. Not polyfills in general. Not Angular or Vue

One is a website, which is using some redirects to wreak havoc. Read More
Angular uses polyfills.ts to

Angular polyfills are JavaScript scripts or modules that are included in an Angular application to ensure compatibility with older browsers. These polyfills enable Angular applications to run smoothly and consistently across different environments, ensuring a consistent user experience.

So both are not related to each other.
What are polyfills?
Understanding Angular Polyfills and the Role of Zone.js
